# how to access repeater label value in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is my javascript

```
  function btnEditClick() {
    alert(document.getElementById('<%=LblRefPhyID.ClientID %>').value);          
  }
```

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterRefPhysicianList" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr onclick="selectRow(this);">
      <td class="csstablelisttd" style="display: none;">
        <asp:Label ID="LblRefPhyID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ref_Phy_ID")%>'></asp:Label>  
      </td>
```

on clientclick of Edit button i have to pass RefphyId to another page how can i do that..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass Control.ClientID in function in repeater ItemDataBound in aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590433/how-to-pass-control-clientid-in-function-in-repeater-itemdatabound-in-aspx-page)

Answer (score 1):

It's a repeater. That means that the `ItemTemplate` will be **repeated** for each item in your databound collection.

This comes with a caveat: IDs are supposed to be unique. So when you say that your `asp:Label` has an ID of `LblRefPhyID`, ASP.NET automagically does you the favor of generating unique IDs for each instance of the repeater that eventually makes its way to your generated HTML. These generated IDs will be based on your original value of `LblRefPhyID`, but it won't be exactly that, so a plain `document.getElementById()` **outside** of the repeater won't work.

There are many ways to work around this, and the very first step you need to do is to actually write some code that will take the automatic generated IDs into account. Maybe write some Javascript to cache the IDs using `LblRefPhyID.ClientID`, maybe do it dynamically `onclick`, whatever.

#### EDIT

And, oh yeah, @Pointy is completely correct in stating that `label` elements don't have values, just their inner HTMLs. I don't get why he got downvoted for giving a correct response.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set css class instead of id and bind elements click event by class name.
I'm using jquery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //bind click event on our label class
  $('.lblRef').live('click', function(){
    alert($(this).text());
   });
});
```

And this in asp.net page code:

```
<asp:Label CssClass="lblRef" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ref_Phy_ID")%>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<label>` elements don't have a "value".  They do have contents:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=LblRefPhyID.ClientID %>').innerHTML);
```

Comment: its not work.unable to find control inside repeater directly.Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Look, `<label>` elements simply **do not have a value**.  They just don't.  You can get the contents, or attributes other than "value", or you can add a non-standard attribute to the markup (which you're not doing, based on what you posted).

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to check what is the pattern of id generated by the repeater on the client side and then you can use that id to get the value of the label using innerHTML.
For instance in your case id generated may be :
`repeaterRefPhysicianList_LblRefPhyID_01` to till the number of rows in source.

So you can use this information with innerHTML to get the value of the label..
All in all just check your html page you will know what to do next :)

Comment: Do not hardcode the ID, use ClientID Property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid?view=netframework-4.8