# How to pass Control.ClientID in function in repeater ItemDataBound in aspx page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clientid

I want to call a JavaScript function to collapse/expand.

I am using this code in asp:repeater `ItemTemplate` on span

```
onclick="javascript:funCollExp(this,'<%= P1.ClientID %>');"
```

How do I pass `Control.ClientID`?

It replaces P1.ClientID as a string on the page.

Comment: check my edit in answer that will help you to get your task done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do like this

```
"onclick="javascript:funCollExp(this,'" + P1.ClinetID + "');"
```

full code for you make use of itemdatabound event like this

**markup**

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" 
       OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:button id="myDiv" runat="server">......</asp:button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**codebehind**

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
           || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      Button mybtn = e.Item.FindControl("mybtn") as bUTTON;

      mybtn.Attributes.Add("ONCLICK", "MYFUNCTION(this,'" + P1.ClientID + "');");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is, use it this way

```
"onclick="javascript:funCollExp(this,'" + P1.ClinetID + "');"
```